# PYTHON SQLITE3 INSERTION: if exist than make addition

Tags: python, sqlite

**Prelumination:**

I have the Table "baseline" in the Sqlite3-DB.
Table "Baseline" has following columns:

1. word
2. counter

**Question:**
Any ideas how it is possible to let sqlite3 engine (if it is more efficient) do for me following operation:

- if table "baseline" already has an element with primary key "word", than while insertion don't replace this row but do addition between old counter and new counter.

**Example**

After following Insertions Commands:

```
"INSERT INTO  baseline(word, counter) VALUES 'bla', 1; "
"INSERT INTO  baseline(word, counter) VALUES 'bla', 1; "
```

I want to get the following data from the DB:

```
>>> "SELECT * FROM baseline;" 
'("bla", 2)'
```

Thx in advance=)

Comment: have you tried `SELECT word, sum(counter) FROM baseline GROUP BY word`?

Comment: thx for the fast responce=) i was thinking about it, but 'word' column has uniq constrain and  I need it for space efficiency.

Comment: then how about summing the counters before inserting?

Comment: yeap, but than i need to extract this row every time from the db. It is also not time efficient. What i want, is to let it happened on the db level, without any row-extraction from the db. Is it possible?=)

Comment: @EgorSavin Your silent on the case when the word doesn't exist. Should we assume nothing happens? or do you need to insert a new word with counter=1?

Comment: sorry,  and thx u for the question. if word not exist, then we need to initialize a new one with given counter=)

Comment: You can also use [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) to do this very cleanly, with the current sqlite version.

Comment: @Shawn thx u, it is also good idea=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If word is a primary key, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE baseline (word TEXT PRIMARY KEY, counter INTEGER);
```

Then the following would work:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO baseline VALUES (
    'foo',
    COALESCE((SELECT counter FROM baseline WHERE word='foo'), 0) + 1
);
```

The `COALESCE()` function returns either the count if word exists in the table, or 0, if not.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a unique constraint on the `word` column then you can do this quite easily with two statements.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO baseline
(word, counter)
VALUES
('bla', 0);
```

Here we either insert a new word with a counter of 0, or if it already exists, then nothing happens.

```
UPDATE baseline
SET counter = counter+1
WHERE word = 'bla';
```

Run this update statement regardless of whether the `word` key already existed. That's why we set `counter` to `0` instead of `1`. This way we don't need any external logic in the code.

Comment: for something more explicit: `update a set counter=(counter+1) where exists (select 1 from a where word = 'foo' limit 1) ;`

Comment: @gregory That won't insert in cases where the `foo` record doesn't exist though. Also, it will increment all `counter` records when `foo` does exist.

Comment: @mypetition, OP doesn't want to insert in cases where `foo` doesn't exist. But, yes, a where predicate needs to be added to the update clause- -thanks.